# OGNL/Struts2 JSP assigning bean to an object

Tags: jsp, parameters, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

In Struts2 / OGNL page, is it possible to assign any type of bean to an object depending on condition?

For instance,

```
  <s:if test"%{customer != null}">
       <s:set var="someobject" value="customer">
  </s:if>
  <s:else>
       <s:set var="someobject" value="user">
  </s:else>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I did not find any similar examples, nor did I know if it works. I had to decide the design based on how it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. But are you sure you should ?

This seems to be business, not presentation, and hence why in the view and not in the controller ?

Instead of

```xml
<s:if test"%{customer != null}">
     <s:set var="someobject" value="customer">
</s:if>
<s:else>
     <s:set var="someobject" value="user">
</s:else>

SomeObject is of type : <s:property value="%{#someobject.class.name}" />
```

You can use in your action

```java
public String getSomeobject(){
    return (customer!=null) ? customer : user;
}
```

and in JSP only

```xml
SomeObject is of type : <s:property value="%{someobject.class.name}" />
```

Your use case is more suitable when your action knows nothing about your objects, but then you would be putting *a lot* of business logic in the view...

Comment: Does `%{someobject.class.name}` actually work? I tried. But it doesn't

Comment: Thank you AleksandrM, fair as always. @KevinRave, in the second s:property you don't need the `#` because `getSomeobject()` is an Action method, and [`The Action instance is always pushed onto the value stack.`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ognl.html), that is the Root of the Context Map.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<s:set>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/set-tag.html) stores variables in the value stack context which is a map. So any object could be set under the key specified in the `var` attribute. If you are using the same key frequently on the page with the `<s:set>` tag then it overrides the previous value set. For example

```jsp
<s:set var="someobject" value="customer">
<s:set var="someobject" value="user">
```

After that you can retrieve only `user` object if you use `someobject` reference.

About references you can read [OGNL](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl) docs.

> The framework uses a standard naming context to evaluate OGNL
> expressions. The top level object dealing with OGNL is a `Map` (usually
> referred as a context map or context). OGNL has a notion of there
> being a root (or default) object within the context. In expression,
> the properties of the root object can be referenced without any
> special "marker" notion. References to other objects are marked with a
> pound sign (`#`).

using above example you can use reference to `someobject` to get a `user` property `name`.

```xml
Hello, <s:property value="#someobject.name"/>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the last sentence please?

Comment: Did you get the last sentence?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in that answer. He provided an answer and threw in a suggestion as well.

Comment: Good answer is an answer that *answers* a question, bad answer lacks it and what is a cost of suggestion that is not related to the question? *Threw a suggestion* sounds like threw a dog a bone.

Comment: Haha. I got your point man! Thanks again. You deserve the credit. But I already accepted the other answer!