# How to use struts2 s:set variable inside s:select tag for list values?

Tags: jsp, select, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I want to use a `s:set` variable inside `s:select`:

```xml
<s:set var="cityNY">NewYork</s:set>

<s:select name="cities" list="#{'%{#cityNY}':'%{#cityNY}'}" required="true" />
```

the above just prints the same value in my page - `%{#cityNY}`

want to display the value if  `s:set` variable in options of `s:select` tag

Comment: How did you do? Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a context variable directly to OGNL expression without `%{}`. It will instantiate a map.

```
<s:select name="cities" list="#{#cityNY:#cityNY}" required="true" />
```

The `list` attribute value can contain an OGNL expression. It is used by default to parse value for OGNL without explicit `%{}`. Subexpressions can be referenced directly inside OGNL expression. `#{exp1:exp2}` is an OGNL expression to instantiate a `Map`. It has subexpressions inside. Each subexpressions should return a single value which is not a collection. Because they used to create a key/value pair for the map.

If you use the same subexpressions then better to instantiate a `List` with the following code

```
<s:select name="cities" list="{#cityNY}" required="true" />
```

It will generate a HTML `<select>` tag with one `<option>` with the same value and text.

If you need more options then you should add values to the OGNL expression with the comma.

The reference docs you can find in my answer to [OGNL/Struts2 JSP assigning bean to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26186622/573032).

Comment: How did you get my answer? If this answer helped you to solve your problem then you should mark it as accepted answer. The checkbox is on the left of the answer.

Comment: Hi @Roman C, I also encounter Ognl expression is not working in 'list' when pass as attribute in radio tag. We are doing migration from struts 2.3.x to struts 2.5.x. And the code <s:radio id="%{#attr.id}" name="%{#attr.name}" list="%{(#attr.ognlExpression)(#attr)}" onclick="%{#attr.onclick}" /> ..value of ognlExpression="#{'Y':'Yes', 'N':'No'}" from parent jsp passed as attribute .This is working before then after migration it is not working anymore. Can you share some solution. Thanks

Comment: @iamcessssy you are doing something complex with ognl. You should move this logic to the action. It is not a good practice to do a complex logic in the view.

Comment: Hi @Roman C, can you explain why it happen? when I put directly the value "#{'Y':'Yes', 'N':'No'}" in the list radio tag like this <s:radio id="%{#attr.id}" name="%{#attr.name}" list="#{'Y':'Yes', 'N':'No'}"" onclick="%{#attr.onclick}" />. It worked well and can read the ognl expression. But when I passed this value dynamically it treated as String Literal and display it in the view as is as the expression "#{'Y':'Yes', 'N':'No'}" and not displaying yes and no option. What are the major changes in ognl in the struts 2.5.x that affects the previous working code?

Comment: @iamcessssy it is because you used ognl to evaluate the expression twice in the struts tag attribute. It is not allowed.